# Using flume to import data from kafka topic to hdfs folder

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, flume, flume-ng

I am using flume to load messages from kafka topic HDFS folder. So,

1. I created a topic **TT**
2. I sent messages to **TT** with a kafka console producer
3. I configured the flume agent **FF**
4. Run the flume agent flume-ng agent -n FF -c conf -f flume.conf -    Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console

The Code Execution Stops, without Error and it doesnot write anything to HDFS. The log file contains this warning
  **No broker partitions consumed by consumer thread flume_-0 for topic**.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: Try to use Flafka [ http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/11/flafka-apache-flume-meets-apache-kafka-for-event-processing/ ], you can find an example in cloudera site with explanation

Comment: You're better off using the [HDFS connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#quickstart) for Kafka Connect. It is open source and available [standalone](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/) or as part of [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/).

Comment: Flume is on its last legs; I agree with @RobinMoffatt that Kafka Connect is the standard way to solve this problem now. If you want to proceed with this, it would be useful to see your `flume.conf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this conf fixed the problem

- FF.sources=kafka-source
- FF.channels = kafka-channel
- FF.sinks =hdfs-sink FF.channels.kafka-channel.type
  org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
- FF.channels.kafka-channel.kafka.bootstrap.servers =
  wided-Latitude:9092
- FF.channels.kafka-channel.kafka.topic = TT
- FF.channels.kafka-channel.parseAsFlumeEvent = false
- FF.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
- FF.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = kafka-channel
- FF.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = hdfs
- FF.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://***:8020/spark/